# Is JBoss 7 a JAX-RS compliant Application Server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jboss7.x

JBoss 7 Application Server is compliant with J2EE 6 Specification.

I just want to know whether JBoss 7 supports JAX-RS implementation or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. The implementation is called [RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) Of course, you can also deploy Jersey, by Sun/Oracle, wich is just a servlet.